Octave calculating extremely slow comparing to Python - Romberg's method
I want to implement Romberg's method in Octave.
Sadly calculating first line of matrix (T_0k method) is working extremely slow comparing to my own Python implementation.
I am using array istead of dictionary but in method mentioned before im not using any data structure.
Problem is in this part of code:
    for i = 0:2^k
        if i == 0 || i == 2^k
            sum = sum + f(x_i(a, i, hk)) / 2;
        else
            sum = sum + f(x_i(a, i, hk));
        end
    end

Why it is happening?
Python code:
import math

def h_k(a, b, k):
    return (b - a)/2**k

def x_i(a, i, h_k):
    return a + i * h_k

def T_0k(k, a, b, f):
    h = h_k(a, b, k)
    sum = 0
    for i in range(2**k + 1):
        if i == 0 or i == 2**k:
            sum += f(x_i(a, i, h))/2
        else:
            sum += f(x_i(a, i, h))

    return h * sum

def T(m, k, d):
    d[(m, k)] = (4**m * d[(m-1, k+1)] - d[(m-1, k)])/(4**m - 1)

def Romberg_tab(a, b, f, m):
    d = {}
    for i in range(m+1):
        d[(0, i)] = T_0k(i, a, b, f)
    for i in range(1, m + 1):
        for j in range(m - i + 1):
            T(i, j, d)

    for m in range(21):
        print(f"T({m},{20 - m}): ", d[(m, 20 - m)])

a = -3
b = 2
def f(x):
    return 2024*x**8 - 1977*x**4 - 1981

Romberg_tab(a, b, f, 20)

Octave code:
disp("result is: ")

function hk = h_k(a, b, k)
    hk = (b - a) / 2^k;
end

function xi = x_i(a, i, hk)
    xi = a + i * hk;
end

function T_0k_result = T_0k(k, a, b, f)
    disp("T_0k_result")

    hk = h_k(a, b, k);
    sum = 0;
    for i = 0:2^k
        if i == 0 || i == 2^k
            sum = sum + f(x_i(a, i, hk)) / 2;
        else
            sum = sum + f(x_i(a, i, hk));
        end
    end
    T_0k_result = hk * sum;
end

function T_result = T(m, k, d)
    disp("T_result")

    T_result = (4^m * d{m - 1, k + 1} - d{m - 1, k}) / (4^m - 1);
end

function d = Romberg_table(a, b, f, m)
    disp("Romberg_table")
    d = cell(m+1, m+1);
    for i = 1:m+1
        d{1, i} = T_0k(i, a, b, f);
    end

    for i = 2:m+1
        for j = 1:m+1-i
            d{i, j} = T(i, j, d);
        end
    end
end

function result = f(x)
    result = 2024 * x^8 - 1977 * x^4 - 1981;
end

a = -3;
b = 2;
m = 20;

d = Romberg_table(a, b, @f, m);



@Wolfie Yes. Sorry for my oversight. Thank you

Octave does not handle looping structures well. that part of the code looks very much like it could be vectorized.  E.g., the entire x_i() looks like it could be calculated at once for the vector i=1:2^k . then f() is just a polynomial evaluation, which can be made to work on a whole vector as well.  which the sum of the whole vector could be calculated.
